# CSS div fixed positioning

Tags: css, html, positioning, css-transitions, fixed

I have a div that contains a smaller div with some text. The container div has a webkit transition that moves it off the screen. I want the smaller div to move with it, until it gets to the edge of the page, then remain fixed, almost as if it gets 'stuck' on the side of the page, while the container div continues to move underneath it out of sight. Can this be done?

```
//CSS
.move{
    -webkit-transition-property:left;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    left:-200px;
}

//HTML
<div onclick="this.className='move'">
     <div>
         some text here
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the inner div to move with the container div until it gets to the side, then remain there while the container continues to move

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LjjRM/

A couple points:

1.) jQuery

2.) position: absolute

Comment: thanks for the quick response, however the inner div is not stopping at the side as requested

Comment: Sorry, I should have read more closely. Would something like this work: http://jsfiddle.net/LjjRM/1/

Comment: I want the inner div to appear within the container div, but stop before it leaves the page, while the container does leave the page. this would be easy with two separate transitions using a linear time function, however i prefer ease-in-out so I'm looking for something that will prevent the inner div from going all the way left